# Running number in a Class

Tags: java, class, static, count

In the following example, I am trying to generate a running as a simple ID for class::`Product`. However, the outcome is not what I had expected.

**My Codes**

```
public class myProgram
{
   public static void main(String[] args)
   {
      Product product1 = new Product("AAA");
      Product product2 = new Product("BBB");
      Product product3 = new Product("CCC");

      System.out.println(product1.printItem());                 
      System.out.println(product2.printItem());
      System.out.println(product3.printItem());
   }
}

class Product
{
   static int productID = 0;
   String name;

   public Product(String startName)
   {
      productID ++;
      name = startName;
   }

   public int printItem()
   {
      return productID;
   }
}
```

**Program Outcome**

```
3
3
3
```

**The outcome I expect it to get is :**

```
1
2
3
```

**My question:** What had I done wrongly to cause the wrong program output?

**EDIT 1:** I placed a static keyword in hoping that it increase `ProductID` after every creation of an instance (Instead of resetting back to 0 every time). If not, how can it be done to generate a running number ?

Comment: cuz product id is static variable?

Comment: @KickButtowski I deliberately made it static in hoping that it adds 1 after every instance of object being created. If not, it will always stay as 0?

Comment: cuz it is kind of universal variable type. everybody can update it. if you want to your expected outcome, you should not use static variable at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a `static` field which means there is only one value.  What you may have intended is to have one static field which is your counter and a member, non-static field which holds the value.

Try changing

```
static int counter = 0;
int productID = 0;
String name;

public Product(String startName) {
    productID = ++counter;
```

If you step through your code in your debugger you would see what your program is actually doing.

Comment: @ThomasJunk How many threads does the OP appear to be using? ;)

Comment: Actually or ever in his life?

Comment: @ThomasJunk  There is any number of things this class might do in his life, why pick that one in particular.  I would have been tempted to add equals/hashCode for example using code generation in my IDE but that doesn't make it a good idea.

Comment: @ThomasJunk "Arguing with an engineer is a lot like wrestling in the mud with a pig. After a few hours, you realize that he likes it."

Answer (score 4):

Because `productId` is static there is only one global value at a time for each of your instances, to match your expected output you would need each instance to have a local `id`. Also, I suggest you replace `printItem()` with `toString()` and/or `getItem()`. Finally, to be thread safe you should probably use [`AtomicInteger`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html),

```
class Product {
  static AtomicInteger productCount = new AtomicInteger(0);
  int productID = 0;
  String name;

  public Product(String startName) {
    productID = productCount.addAndGet(1);
    name = startName;
  }

  public int getItemId() {
    return productId;
  }

  @Override
  public String toString(){
    return String.valueOf(productID);
  }
}
```

Comment: I am already using toString() for printing, I actually retype all my codes in here to make it simpler and address my concerns directly.

Comment: Note: `++` is not atomic so in multithread environment it is better to use `AtomicInteger` as `productCount` type.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch It is not always a good idea to over engineer your solutions.  Sometimes it is best to just have the code do what is needed.  We could use AtomicLong instead in case we have over 2 bn products, add equals, hashCode, compareTo, cache the toString(), where to stop if we add all the things we imagine we might need. ;)

Comment: @PeterLawrey While sometimes the glass is twice as big as it needs to be, to hold a pint you need a pint glass!

Comment: @ElliottFrisch we can't always predict how much force a glass might endure in it's life and maybe we are working on a project where we can't predict whether we have one thread or more, but I suggest we avoid such projects. ;)

Answer (score 2):

Because static variable is shared between objects that have just one copy for all the object. you can say one copy for whole class.

A static variable (or **class variable**) is one that belongs to the class itself, rather than to the objects of the class.

See *Java Tutorial* on [Understanding Class Members](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html)

[Read more...](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~matuszek/General/JavaSyntax/static.html)

Try to understand it visually.

[image]

Comment: I am trying to understand the logics, you made it really clear and straight to the point. +1 for you. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Because `productID` was defined `static`

Note: Static variable’s value is same for all the object(or instances) of the class or in other words you can say that all instances(objects) of the same class share a single copy of static variables.

Source: http://beginnersbook.com/2013/05/static-variable/

Answer (score 1):

You have

```
static int productID = 0;
```

Here `static` means `productID` belongs to the class Product and not to instances of Product. All instances share the **same** `ProductID`

Use instead

```
int productID = 0
```

Then each instance will have it's own copy. You will need to find another way to set the value ...

Answer (score 1):

Because you have made ProductID static, it's value will be shared by all objects of type Product.  My Suggestions would be to create a variable in your main function which you increment each time a product is created and pass it in as a parameter.

Edit: @DavidPostill -- Then they will all be equal to 1.